# Show that $R=\lbrace (a,b): 5\mid(a^2-b^2) \rbrace$ is an equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

How can I show that this is an equivalence relation ?

$$R=\lbrace (a,b):  5\mid(a^2-b^2) \rbrace$$

Comment: Assuming it's a relation on the integers, where's the problem in proving the relation is reflexive ($(a,a)\in R$, for all $a$), symmetric (if $(a,b)\in R$, then $(b,a)\in R$) and transitive (if $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,c)\in R$, then $(a,c)\in R$)?

Comment: @egreg I thought that I have to use $a$ and $b$ in pair, but now  you've shown me that's not as I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equivalence relation needs to be reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

- $aRa$
- $aRb \implies bRa$
- $aRb$ and $bRc \implies aRc$

So in this case, is it true that:

- $5|(a^2-a^2)$
- if $5|(a^2-b^2)$ then $5|(b^2-a^2)$
- if $5|(a^2-b^2)$ and $5|(b^2-c^2)$ then $5|(a^2-c^2)$

?

Comment: Can I ask you one more question related to this exercise ?

Comment: My question was stupid, but there is still a thing, how can I determine the classes of equivalence. I know that when determining this, I should have a result, and if $n$ elements give the same result, they create a class. But in this case,I have that 5 divides something,that gives only whether it's true or it's false,so, how can I specify what are the classes, how should I think ?

Comment: Transitivity means that items that are related to each other aggregate into classes. If you know $a$ is not related to $d$, then nothing else that $a$ is related can be related to $d$ either. In this case, $a^2 \bmod 5$ will determine class.

Answer (score 3):

This is often a source of confusion among beginners, so I'll try to explain where the problem is.

Everybody knows intuitively what a relation among elements of a set is; examples from the real world are “being a parent of”, “being siblings”, “being taller” and so on.

However, *defining* what a relation is becomes circular, so in mathematics a more pragmatic approach is followed:

> *a relation is a set consisting of ordered pairs*

If $R$ is a set of ordered pairs, or a relation, we say that $R$ is a *relation on the set* $A$ if, for all $(x,y)\in R$, we have $x\in A$ and $y\in A$.

For instance, the empty relation is a relation on every set. If $A$ is any set, the relation $\{(x,x):x\in A\}$ is a relation on $A$, usually called the identity on $A$.

A relation $R$ on a set $A$ is said

- *reflexive* when, for all $a\in A$, $(a,a)\in R$;
- *symmetric* when, for all $a,b\in A$, if $(a,b)\in R$, then $(b,a)\in R$;
- *transitive* when, for all $a,b,c\in A$, if $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,c)\in R$, then $(a,c)\in R$.

The three properties together are shortened into saying that $R$ is an *equivalence relation* on $A$.

Where does the confusion start from? An alternative notation for $(a,b)\in R$ is $a\mathrel{R}b$. You should remember that you need to test *two* elements, when talking about an instance of the relation.

---

Your relation is probably defined on the integers. So you have to answer the following questions:

1. Does $5\mid a^2-a^2$, for all $a\in\mathbb{Z}$? This gives “$(a,a)\in R$”.
2. Does $5\mid a^2-b^2$ imply $5\mid b^2-a^2$? This gives “if $(a,b)\in R$, then $(b,a)\in R$.
3. Do the conditions $5\mid a^2-b^2$ and $5\mid b^2-c^2$ imply $5\mid a^2-c^2$?

Comment: Thank you very much, the confusion was that I thought that I should use $a$ and $b$ in pair, but that was stupid, thank you for your clear presentation of equivalence notion.